# mule dynamically setting soap operation

Tags: mule

In my flow I have a soap client calling a service. Since we are using 3 different operations from the service I'd like to dynamically fill in the "Operation" field under "Client Attributes" in Mule soap component. The way I have it working right now is:

```
start flow -> message transformation -> choice flow control (based on the message type) 
choice 1. sub flow A -> soap client with operation A 
choice 2. sub flow B -> soap client with operation B 
choice 3. sub flow C -> soap client with operation C
```

What I would like is to dynamically in runtime set the "Operation" field based on the message and not have three different subflows.

```
start flow -> message transformation -> set the operation field -> soap client with the correct operation
```

Is that possible? Using Mule CE 3.3.1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "Mule soap component"? Is it a `cxf:jaxws-client`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to change the cxf:jaxws-client operation attribute at runtime since we're 3 different operations from the same service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal:

- Remove the `operation` attribute from the `cxf:jaxws-client` element,
- Add set the operation as an outbound message property before the `cxf:jaxws-client` element with:

  ```
  <set-property propertyName="operation" value="#[...]" />
  ```

  where `#[...]` represents a MEL expression that extracts the operation name from the message.

Comment: Thanks David, works like a charm. I set the an operation property in the header based on the message type and then, as you recommended, extracted with MEL the operation value and set it as follows: '<set-    property propertyName="operation" value="#[header:INVOCATION:cxf_ops]"    doc:name="extractOps"/>'  Now I only have one subflow that does all three operations, perfect, thanks again.

Comment: Glad it works! Suggestion: use MEL instead of the old style / deprecated expression syntax, ie: `<set-property propertyName="operation" value="#[flowVars.cxf_ops]"/>`

Comment: Yup, good suggestion. I will change it and test it out. Thank you.