# Mule ESB -Error when dynamically setting Soap Operation in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

Please help me on this error.I have a soap client calling the service with 3 operation. So in flow1 i'm setting the session varaible to store the operation. And in flow2 i have used **set property** to accessing those variables to come as outbound message Property before the **cxf:jaxws-client.** As descripted in this link: [mule dynamically setting soap operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533402/mule-dynamically-setting-soap-operation) but i'm getting exception like "local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName".

I have monitored by keeping logger after **set property**. Can able to see the operation with values in outbound message property. Not sure why the value is not placed in soap operation field.Please find my xml config.

```
         <flow name="Flow1" doc:name="eFlow" tracking:enable-default-events="false">
          <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="InputQ"  connector ref="WMQ_Connector" doc:name="connector">
           <wmq:transaction action="NONE"/>
          </wmq:inbound-endpoint>
           <set-session-variable variableName="cxf_operation"
        value="#[xpath('fn:local-name(/root/*[2])')]" doc:name="Set_Operation" />
          <some logic here.../>
        </flow>

        <flow name="Service_call" doc:name="Service">
        <set-property propertyName="operation" value="#[sessionVars.cxf_operation]"
        doc:name="Property" />
        <logger message="***outbound properties: #[message.outboundProperties]***" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
 <cxf:jaxws-client  enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP" serviceClass="com.valid.ICase"/>
   <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
                method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"         address="http://localhost:8085/callingService" />
  <some logic here.../>
   </flow>
```

I havn't set soap operation since i have set property. Still i'm getting error. Can anyone help on this. 
But when i manually type the operation name. Able to see the response.

Comment: Can you show your payload?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `operation` of the CXF jaxws-client is taken when it is inside the `cxf:jaxws-client` element tag.
So you can declare the `operation` in the `cxf:jaxws-client` tag.

Second thing is the `operation` attribute in the cxf:jaxws-client cannot evaluate `Mule Expression Language`. So it cannot take MEL expressions. It can take only String. That is the reason it is working when you type it manually and not loading dynamically.

Check Mule Jira if there is any such issue reported.

[Mule Jira](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting exception like "local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName"

The `operation` property you're setting should be a `javax.xml.namespace.QName`. So you need to extract the namespace URI and local part from `sessionVars.cxf_operation` and use [this QName constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html#QName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in the `set-property` before the `cxf:jaxws-client`.

This assumes that `sessionVars.cxf_operation` is of the form `{namespaceURI}localPart`. If that is not the case, and it actually only contains the `localPart` then you'll have to hard code the namespace URI in the `QName` constructor, using the hopefully unique namespace into which all the operations are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it before cxf:jaxws-client

```
<set-variable value="#[message.inboundProperties['operation']]" variableName="operation" />
```